# Tunnelling through multiple machines on Red Hat with varying users and keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm trying to SSH tunnel hop to a Tomcat7 server where JMX was configured on port 9090.

Essentially: `localhost > hostB > hostC`.

In a terminal, from localhost to hostB:

`ssh -L 8989:localhost:8989 me@hostB`

Once connected to hostB, I'll enter the following command to connect to hostC:

`sudo -u userA ssh userB@hostC -i /path/to/key -p 21559 -L 8989:localhost:9090`

In VisualVM, I attempt to connect to localhost:8989 but get `"Cannot connect to localhost:8989 using service:jmx:rmi..."`.

The configuration of Tomcat/JMX is the same as the other servers located inside the firewall. Those were previously confirmed accessible with VisualVM.

All commands work without the forwarding of ports. I'm able to interact with hostC without any issues. I simply cannot tunnel at this point.

**Update #1**

Using netstat from hostC:

```
[userB@hostC ~]$ netstat -an | grep 8989
[userB@hostC ~]$ netstat -an | grep 9090
tcp        0      0 :::9090           :::*                        LISTEN
```

With a terminal looking like this:

```
[userB@hostC ~]$
```

In another terminal, I entered the following:

```
telnet localhost 8989
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'
```

Seems like it's connected?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, assuming you are not observing any errors with ssh. I would test with telnet to port 8989 and also look at netstat -an for listening connections and make sure you see connections being established all the way

Comment: Once connected to hostB, netstat -an | grep 8989 should return something? In my case, nothing is returned. No errors in terms of SSH.

Comment: On hostC you should see connections on 8989 and what does telnet to localhost:8989 give?

Comment: I've added update #1 with the details you asked for